# Elementary divisor theorem for integer matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisibility

Does anyone have a reference for the elementary divisor theorem which states that for any $2\times2$ integer matrix $A$, there exist matrices $P$ and $Q$ in $SL(2,Z)$ such that $PAQ$ is a diagonal matrix ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like the treatment Jacobson gives in his

> N. Jacobson. Basic algebra. I. W. H. Freeman and Company, New York, 1974 and 1985.

Perhaps you might want to search for it.

Comment: Thanks. I learned it a long time ago but now I forgot how to prove it.

Comment: It's a nice algorithm indeed. And thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Called Smith Normal Form. One book is *Integral Matrices* by Newman.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form